# swfobject not working in firefox 3?

Tags: javascript, flash

My javascript code as follows:

```
BBS.SO = new SWFObject("/Client/Css/sound.swf", "mysound", "1", "1", "8", "#336699");

BBS.SO.write('swfholder');
```

it used to work,but not now in firefox,but in iE it still works.

Is there such a bug with swfobject?it's a opensource project.

it seems in firefox3,there is a great delay when inserting such an embed into a div element:

```
<embed id="mysound" height="1" width="1" quality="high" bgcolor="#336699" name="mysound" style="" src="/Client/Css/sound.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

Is it really a bug with firefox3?any work-around?

Or you can check out this testing page,

http://maishudi.com/test.php

with IE you'll hear a sound,

but for firefox3 users,it's quiet...

Answer (score 1):

Your example page played a sound in Firefox 3.0.10 for me on both Ubuntu (Jaunty) and 32-bit Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the sound my Blackberry makes when I get an IM.

Comment: It sometimes played a sound here too,but most of the time 2 minutes or more after I opened the page...
There should be actually something wrong there.